# Why is one API response returning just an object over and array of objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach, axios, sequelize.js

Currently my Api is returning an object instead of an object within an array, however I can't seem to tell the difference between these two routes and why one would return said array of data over the other.

For instance :

```
router.get('/caseDetail/:id', (req,res) => {
db.caseDetail.findOne({
    include : [db.Part,db.Fault,db.Disposition,db.Contact,db.Site]
}).then((response) => {
    res.json(response);
}).catch((error) => {
    console.table([stack.error,stack.id,error])
})
})
```

The above route returns an array of data while the following returns just an object

```
router.get('/caseDetail/:caseName', (req,res) => {
    db.caseDetail.findAll({
        
        include : [db.Part,db.Fault,db.Disposition,db.Contact,db.Site],
        where : {
            caseName:{ 
              [Op.like]: req.params.caseName}
        }
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        res.json(response)
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    })
})
```

-------------------------- **For context**---------------------------- 
I've enacted this method multiple times, even in other script files, but I haven't been required to parse data in this manner, is something out of shape here that im over looking? Am I missing a JSON.parse(); here? [Github](https://github.com/fleshborne/rma-inventory/blob/master/public/assets/js/searchInventory.js)

```
  try { 
                  const items = await axios.get(`/api/caseDetail/:caseName` + caseName);
                console.log(items.data); 
                $tbody.empty()
                items.data.forEach((item) => {
                    console.log(item);
```

Returned Results

```
{id: 2, caseName: "1 - Fenway Park - 1", createdAt: "2021-07-27T18:13:55.000Z", updatedAt: "2021-07-27T18:13:55.000Z", UserId: 1, …}
```

Error Message

```
TypeError: items.data.forEach is not a function
    at callSearchResults (searchInventory.js:29)
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like an object so you can't use forEach.

Comment: these results are returned after the call to my API route, giving me the data, yet it wont loop through it, sure theres only 1 item that's being returned as only one thing exists in the DB at the moment, yet this error shouldn't persist.

Comment: You need to return the object in an array, if you want to loop using .forEach()

Comment: It's an array of objects, the console you're specifically seeing is a log of items.data

Comment: the log you showed, isn't an array. But an object.

Comment: So the issues exists more so on my api route and not the function call itself?

Comment: Yes, because it's not returning an array of objects. Just an object.

Comment: eh, not technically an issue with the api route, if it's a route meant to return one "item", it shouldn't be an array (and therefore there wouldn't likely be a reason to even use forEach)

Comment: the route is meant to return all that fit the search params entered by user, which previously only one existed so it kind of made sense that it wasn't an array. Not sure why I was downvoted for clarity when the question is outlined well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly and this is the result that you receive from your request:

```
{id: 2, caseName: "1 - Fenway Park - 1", createdAt: "2021-07-27T18:13:55.000Z", updatedAt: "2021-07-27T18:13:55.000Z", UserId: 1, …}
```

Then you would need to take the entries out of it and iterate over them like so:

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(items)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

Or like this:

```
Object.entries(items).forEach(([key, val]) => console.log(key, val));
```

Answer (score -3):

**forEach()** is designed for arrays but you can typecast collections and objects into arrays like this...

```
var I=[...items];

var D=[...items.data]
```

Now you should be OK, try...

```
I.data.forEach((item) => {}

D.forEach(() => {}
```

Comment: Sadly this resulted in an error, where items is not iterable